# Is there a way to distinguish between 2 optical drives when opening and closing with PowerShell?

Tags: windows-8, powershell, code

Is there a way to distinguish between my 2 disk drives when executing-

```
$cd = Add-Type -memberDefinition @"
[DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] public static extern int mciSendStringA(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);
"@ -passthru -name mciSendString
$cd::mciSendStringA('set cdaudio door open', $null, 0, 0);
```

through Windows Powershell? Or am I just stuck with the command opening my bluray drive instead of my DVD drive?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this: [C# Open Close
Multiple Disk Drives](http://www.vcskicks.com/disk-drive.php)? Notice, that there is a way to specify drive letter:

> To open the disk drive you need to send two command strings using
>   mciSendStringA. The first one will assign a name to the desired drive.
>   The second command will actually open the disk tray:

```
mciSendStringA("open " + driveLetter + ": type CDaudio alias drive" + driveLetter, 
                 returnString, 0, 0);
mciSendStringA("set drive" + driveLetter + " door open", returnString, 0, 0);
```

You can get drive info (letter, type and so on) in PowerShell using static [GetDrives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx) method from [DriveInfo Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx):

```powershell
[System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives()
```

Here is the this PowerShell version of the C# code above:

```powershell
$Winmm = Add-Type -MemberDefinition @"
[DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] public static extern int mciSendStringA(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);
"@ -PassThru -Name mciSendString

# Replace X with your DVD drive letter
$DvdDrive = 'X'

$Winmm::mciSendStringA("open ${DvdDrive}: type CDaudio alias drive$DvdDrive", $null, 0, 0);
$Winmm::mciSendStringA("set drive$DvdDrive door open", $null, 0, 0);
```